# what is the NLTK equivalent of the UIMA CAS (common annotation structure)?

Tags: nlp, nltk, uima

In UIMA, the [CAS](https://uima.apache.org/downloads/releaseDocs/2.1.0-incubating/docs/html/references/references.html#ugr.ref.cas) (common annotating structure) plays a major role in structuring an NLP application. It allows to pass the metadata that one components adds into the next compoment. For example, sentence boundaries from a sentence tokenizer can be added to the CAS and used by the subsequent word tokenizer.

What is the equivalent data structure in [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, there is no equivalent concept to the CAS (Common Analysis System) in NLTK. The latter uses much simpler means of representing texts than does UIMA. In NLTK, [texts are simply lists of words](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html#a-closer-look-at-python-texts-as-lists-of-words), whereas in UIMA you have very complex (and heavy-weight) data structures defined as part of the CAS for the purpose of describing the input data and its flow through a UIMA system.

That being said, I view the two of them to serve quite different purposes anyway. If I was to name a Java equivalent for NLTK, I would choose the [OpenNLP toolkit](https://opennlp.apache.org/) rather than UIMA. The former offers a number of algorithms for NLP based on machine learning (as does NLTK, among other things), while the latter is a component-based framework not only for NLP, but unstructured data in general. That is, it defines a general model for building applications working with unstructured data.